# Executor thread keeps running after main class is finished

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code which runs on a simple main activity:

```
 Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {

            System.out.println("sleep");
            Thread.sleep(5000); 



        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          System.out.println("Interrupted, so exiting.");
        }
      }
    });
```

It looks like that when i run this code application doesnt terminate and nothing gets printed either (except the first sleep).

On the other hand when i run this:

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
```

application terminates just fine. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
});
```

With this, the thread will terminate after executing the `run` method.

```
Runnbale r = ...
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.execute(r);
```

With this, the executor will create a thread which works like below:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(notShutdown()) {
            waitingForTask(); // may get blocked
            runTask(); // execute Runnable user submits
        }
    }
});
```

This thread will not terminate after the first task, it will keep waiting for new tasks. You need call [`executor.shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) explicitly.

Comment: What do they mean by "has no remaining threads". Can you  delete  threads from a pool?

Comment: @Nick See my update. Threads will not be deleted, but they will terminate after executing the run method.

Comment: Im confused with the "A pool that is no longer referenced in a program AND has no remaining threads". When does this happen?

Comment: When you [allowCoreThreadTimeOut](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#allowCoreThreadTimeOut(boolean))

Comment: Oh i see but both conditions must be met. If there are no threads after timeout but there still is a reference to the pool it will not shutdown

Comment: @Gray In the answer, I have explained the working thread in the pool will keep waiting for task when `notShutdown`

Answer (score 2):

[Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface would not allow you to shutdown the service. Preferred way is to use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead of Executor

```
ExecutorService executorService =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(factory);
  executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    try {
     doTask();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     logger.error("indexing failed", e);
    }
   }
  });
  executorService.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Executor thread keeps running after main class is finished

Yep, it's designed to do that.  The whole point of an `ExecutorService` is that there is a pool of threads. Even though the `Runnable` that you submitted has finished, the threads in the pool are waiting for other jobs to come along.  You need to shutdown the pool to get your application to terminate.

> It looks like that when i run this code the application doesn't terminate and nothing gets printed either (except the first sleep).

The right way to use the `ExecutorService` is something like the following:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
threadPool.submit(new Runnable() ...);
// submit any other jobs to the pool here
...
// after last submit, you shutdown the pool, submitted jobs will continue to run
threadPool.shutdown();
// optionally wait for all jobs to finish in pool, similar to thread.join()
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Once you shutdown the pool and the jobs that have submitted finish, the threads in the pool will terminate and, if there are no more non-daemon threads, your application will stop.

Answer (score 0):

- Cause

: You did not  shutdown the executor .And When you do the shutdown be aware to do it after it's termination

- Solution

  : shut it down only after its termination using a simple code.

For example :

`executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}`

- Another solution is to use ExecutorCompletionService  if you want to take tasks as they complete you need an ExecutorCompletionService. This acts as a BlockingQueue that will allow you to poll for tasks as and when they finish.

Comment: `ExecutorCompletionService` doesn't quite make sense in the case of this question.  You might consider removing it.

Comment: When using an  ExecutorCompletionService.poll/take, you are receiving the Futures as they finish, in completion order (more or less).So you should be able to check deeply the termination of each taske and it will be like a task monitoring through it you can control all tasks and manipulate them.If that is not related directly to the subject it could be a useful idea to use .

Comment: It's very difficult to get ECS implementations right and even if you _did_ handle the OP's sleep task that way, it wouldn't solve the shutdown issue.  IMO this overly complicates an otherwise good answer.

Comment: Yes i agree with you.